# aws codecommit cannot push

Tags: git, security, amazon-web-services, credentials, aws-codecommit

I setup my new repo in aws codecommit. I'm totally new to this.

I can clone my repo using this

```
git clone ssh://APKAISIJVIU6XXXXXX@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/weewee my-demo-repo
```

However when I try to push I get this message

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.

I setup the config file and the credentials as instructed in AWS.

I can't find what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have multiple public keys in your `~/.ssh` directory?

If you have an `id_rsa.pub` in `~/.ssh` but did not choose to upload that one to the IAM console then you will need to configure your `.ssh/config` to use the public key that you chose with the user name that you are specifying.

For example, if you have created and uploaded the public key named `codecommit_rsa.pub` (per the documentations), then you will need to add the following lines to your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  User APKAISIJVIU6XXXXXX
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
```

Let me know if this helps!

Yilun