# Git clone works in AWS CodeCommit but pushing fails with 403

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, git-push, aws-codecommit

I can clone my CodeCommit repository successfully, but when I try to push to it, I get 403. Fetching and pulling works, however. It's as if I have read-only access.

I have setup my `.gitconfig` to use AWS CLI for credential manager:

```
[credential]
        helper = !aws --profile builder codecommit credential-helper $@
        UseHttpPath = true
```

The problem is that the error doesn't tell me why pushing is failing:

```
$ git push origin test-branch
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-example-repo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Most questions on the internet about his error are when cloning fails, but cloning works for me. I found this question where cloning succeeds and pushing fails, but his error is different - [aws codecommit cannot push](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39904327/492336).

**Edit:**: After looking at my CodeCommit policy, it has `Full: Read Limited: List, Write`:

[image]

There is also a `ResourceSpecifier = foo-*`, but that holds for `GitPull` permission and pulling works, so I doubt it's the resource specifier.

Comment: Is this on a mac or windows?

Comment: I'm on Windows.

Comment: Ok, how are you using git on windows? Do you have a credentials manager installed? Using Eclipse? Visual Studio? Git Bash or Cygwin? And versions of how you are using git.

Comment: I use git bash for Windows from the official site. But keep in mind that cloning and pulling already work. Most of the problems you have in mind would have prevented me from cloning, not just pushing.

Comment: What's the full IAM policy your user has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you're right about the read-only permissions. As the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control-permissions-reference.html#aa-git) state, you need the `codecommit:GitPush` permission in your IAM policy to be allowed to push commits from your local repository to the CodeCommit repository.

Being able to pull the repository means your credentials are set up correctly, if they weren't you wouldn't be able to `git pull` / `git fetch` at all.

Comment: I updated my question with details about my IAM policy.

Comment: Could you include your actual policy? It'll have the actual specific permissions you have as opposed to 'limited' which could be any number of things.

Comment: I found it it was indeed the `ResourceSpecifier`. After changing it in the Policy so it matched my repo name, it started working. I'll accept your answer since it led me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

For MacOS: Delete the code-commit internet passwords in Keychain and try again. Also:

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tom's answer sent me in the right direction. To expand on it, the reason was that my user had a write permissions only for repositories whose name matches a certain pattern containing wildcards.

This pattern is from the policy JSON, and looks like this:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:*:*:bar*"
```

This pattern would give me write access to any repository whose names starts with `bar`, so I could push to a repo named `bar` or `bar2`, but not to a repo named `foo-bar` because it doesn't start with `bar` even though it contains it.